# Analogy between elliptic curves and number fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

The first section of [this](http://delaunay.perso.math.cnrs.fr/heuristics_2.pdf) article describes a deep analogy between elliptic curves and number fields. In particular, there is the analogy between the Tate-Shafarevich group for an elliptic curve and the ideal class group of a number field. Presumably, this particular analogy is due to the fact that both arise in similar cohomological circumstances, as discussed in [this](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/why_is_an_ideal_class_group_a_tate_schaferevich_group.pdf) paper. Are there any other books, papers, or sources that describe this analogy and prove, as in the second paper, that the "Tate-Shafarevich group" of a number field is indeed the ideal class group?

Answer (score 3):

This was, in fact, the topic of an REU paper I wrote last year, which can be found [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Kailasa.pdf)!

Comment: You ask in the paper something to the effect of: "In what sense does the class group measure local-global failure." I think the idea is the following: Suppose you are given order of vanishing locally at each place (ie, you are given a divisor), then you can ask if there is a global function of which the divisor is the zeroes - poles. This is in contrast to the elliptic curve case where you are given points on $X(K_v)$ and want a point on $X(K)$ for X a torsor of E. This is not really all that direct or satisfying and you probably were thinking along these lines anyway...